# Update SQL Query in Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: mysql, vba

I'm encountering a problem with my SQL Query in this code:

```
Private Sub bttnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttnsave.Click

    strsql ="UPDATE client_tbl set remarks_notes ='" & richtextboxnotes.Text & "', 
             land_line_number = '" & txtlandline.Text & "',
             cellphone_number = '" & txtcellphone.Text & "',
             sex = '" & combogender.Text & "',
             email = '" & txtemail.Text & "',
             birth_year = '" & comboyear.Text & "',  
             birth_day = '" & comboday.Text & "', 
             birth_month = '" & combomonth.Text & "', 
             address = '" & txtaddress.Text & "', 
             position = '" & txtposition.Text & "', 
             company = '" & txtcompany.Text & "', 
             last_name = '" & txtlname.Text & "', 
             middle_name = '" & txtmname.Text & "', 
             first_name = '" & txtfname.Text & "', 
             salutation ='" & txtsalutation.Text & "', 
             developer = '" & txtdeveloper.Text & "', 
                    WHERE client_id = '" & lblid.Text & "'"

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strsql, connection)
        da.Fill(ds)
        Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

I receiving this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB Server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'WHERE client_id = '3'' at line 1
```

When I do update a record in my Database.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  Your current question is not readable.

Comment: *Don't* build queries using string concatenation. Use parameterized queries with `MySqlCommand` and pass the values as *parameters*. Not only do you avoid SQL Injection attacks, you also avoid conversion errors and misspellings like this one. As it is, your query is unmaintainable

Comment: Sorry i'm new here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string concatenation to create a SQL query is a very serious bug that exposes you to SQL Injection attacks, conversion errors when passing dates and numbers, and, as in this case, misspellings.

Just think of all the security breaches you've heard in the last couple of months *alone*.

You should use parameterized queries with the [MySqlCommand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) object instead:

```
   Dim sql As String= "UPDATE client_tbl set remarks_notes = @remarks, land_line_number = @landLine, ... WHERE client_id = @clientId"
   Dim cmd as New MySqlCommand(sql,connection)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks",richtextboxnotes.Text)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@landLine",txtlandline.Text)
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientId",lblid.Text)
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

You don't need to use MySqlDataAdapter because `UPDATE` doesn't return any results.

Answer (score -1):

The part

```
strsql = "UPDATE client_tbl set remarks_notes = '" & richtextboxnotes.Text & "', `land_line_number = '" & txtlandline.Text & "', cellphone_number = '" & txtcellphone.Text & "', sex = '" & combogender.Text & "', email = '" & txtemail.Text & "', birth_year = '" & comboyear.Text & "',  birth_day = '" & comboday.Text & "', birth_month = '" & combomonth.Text & "', address = '" & txtaddress.Text & "', position = '" & txtposition.Text & "', company = '" & txtcompany.Text & "', last_name = '" & txtlname.Text & "', middle_name = '" & txtmname.Text & "', first_name = '" & txtfname.Text & "', salutation ='" & txtsalutation.Text & "', developer = '" & txtdeveloper.Text & "', WHERE client_id = '" & lblid.Text & "'"`
```

Before WHERE you have and extra comma.

Also, try to split the query if it is too long to help you read it too.

For example:

```
strsql = "UPDATE client_tbl set remarks_notes = '" & richtextboxnotes.Text & "', land_line_number = '" & txtlandline.Text 
strsql = strsql & "', cellphone_number = '" & txtcellphone.Text & "', sex = '" & combogender.Text & "', email = '" & txtemail.Text 
strsql = strsql & "', birth_year = '" & comboyear.Text & "',  birth_day = '" & comboday.Text & "', birth_month = '" & combomonth.Text 
strsql = strsql & "', address = '" & txtaddress.Text & "', position = '" & txtposition.Text & "', company = '" & txtcompany.Text 
strsql = strsql & "', last_name = '" & txtlname.Text & "', middle_name = '" & txtmname.Text & "', first_name = '" & txtfname.Text 
strsql = strsql & "', salutation ='" & txtsalutation.Text & "', developer = '" & txtdeveloper.Text & "' WHERE client_id = '" & lblid.Text & "'"`
```

Comment: Better yet, avoid string concatenation completely and use parameterized queries. You avoid SQL Injection attacks, conversion problems and unreadable code. That 6-line concatenation is simply unmaintainable

Comment: Oh i see thank you very much for your help! i'm only a newbie in visual basic. now i have a problem with the updating record. suppose to the middle name is in the text box of middle name but the middle name is in the first name. what should i do. THANK YOU @encryptoferia